# Image cannot be display after uploading

Tags: php, image

Previously, when I tried uploading image into the database, the image won't display. When I check the path in the db and in the folder, it is correct.

Correct path in db and folder.
[image]

[image]

And then when I tried to view the image that has been uploaded it says that I don't have the permission to view it.

[image]

I have also tried uploaded different photo extension and different photo viewer application and I still cannot view the image. Apart from that, I have tried 
[W3School PHP5 File Upload.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) Again same thing happen, I cannot view my image.

This is my code :

```
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
    $location= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ehars/photo/' . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ehars/photo/' . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo (location,emp_id) VALUES ('$location','$emp_id')");                  
}
```

Why can't I view my image? Is it because of the document root? Or is it something else? Please help me thank you.

**UPDATED :**

Based on the image below, my code (as shown above) is inside the *admin* folder. The reason why I would like to save my images in /ehars/photos so that, every level of user, *admin* *admin2* and *user* can view the same photo that has been uploaded. If you could advice me what is the best way to do in order to achieve my objective above. Thanks again!

[image]

Comment: What are the permissions set on the server?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/window-photo-viewer-cant-open-this-picture-because/05e31f84-75ab-4772-84a5-5ce0e6e71f61

Comment: @Huey sorry but I'm new to this so what do you mean by the permissions set on the server?

Comment: @Huey you should *never* need 755. 444 is the widest permission you should ever need for static content. The script that accesses it might need 644 so it can read/write to the file location, but that's about it. Images don't need execution rights: if they're scripts that were uploaded with an image extension the execution rights is the best way to guarantee you're going to end up with a compromised system.

Answer (score 1):

If your URL scheme is not "file://", you should authorized your browser.
I remember that you can't easily link CSS and image to the local machine due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

change your code into this

```
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
    $location='/ehars/photo/' . $_FILES["image"]["name"]; //remove $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], '/ehars/photo/' . $_FILES["image"]["name"]); // remove $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo (location,emp_id) VALUES ('$location','$emp_id')");                  
}
```

why tou should change your code, because your server not gonna read windows path (c:/apache/htdocs/yourimagespath/yourimages.jpg); it should read (/images/yourimages.jpg), i asume htdocs is your root directory. and the result in your database is /ehars/photo/yourimages.jpg not c:/apache/htdoc/ehars/photo/yourimages.jpg.

hope it help you.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your help. I guess what you're saying is true about the folder path. I have tried removing the $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in my code. However, there is no image of the image that i have upload in my folder photo. I've updated my problem above to help you understand my problem better. Thank you again!